# Are "Word Origin" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Are questions which ask solely about the origin of a phrase such as this https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32963/what-is-the-origin-of-phrase-breaking-down-silos considered on-topic?

Answer (score 2):

By itself the question is off topic here. I can see a question that asks "What does this phrase mean and where did it come from?"  In that case it is on topic because it is about navigating the work place.

Example:

> My coworkers keep saying to give them the pickle.(them being our customers) what does that mean and where does that saying come from?

Then an answer with links to [this site](http://www.giveemthepickle.com) and explaining what it means would make sense and be on topic.